# MS Access 2010 Form_Timer event firing only once

Tags: forms, vba, timer, ms-access-2010

Having some firing issues with the timer associated with a form, can anyone tell me why this is not working, and only firing once.
Here is the code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckingToggle_Click()
    If Me.CheckingToggle.value = False Then
        Me.TimerInterval = 0
        Text35.value = 0
    Else
        Me.TimerInterval = 5000
        Text35.value = 5000
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    CheckingToggle.value = False
    Me.TimerInterval = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()

If CheckingToggle = True Then

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    'The sql here is operating on the Access Jet tables dont get confused if trying to Mysql functions will not work!!!!
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM DataMonitor WHERE IsActive=true " _
        & " And ( " _
        & " DateAdd('n', [FrequencyMins], [LastCheck]) < #" & Now() & "#" _
        & " OR IsNull([LastCheck]))")

    'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit
        Do Until rs.EOF = True
            'Do our stuff here

            DoEvents

        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "There are no records that are Active which have not been ckecked in the last minute"
    End If

    rs.Close 'Close the recordset
    Set rs = Nothing 'Clean up

End If
End Sub
```

After clicking the toggle to 'checked', the timer fires for the first time and a break-point on the first line of the Form_Timer() catches the execution, and a watch shows that the interval was set correctly to 5000, but, irrespective of clicking the toggle on and off or not, it never fires again until the form is first put back in design mode.

Something that seems odd though is that after continuing from the break-point, if I go to switch the form to design mode without first stopping the running code, which the header says is running, I am blocked! "you can switch to a different view at this time" ...as if the timer is running just the event not firing. At least the break-point does not catch it.

I tried puting a counter in the sub, just to test if the process was passing-through without tripping the breakpoint somehow, but this did'nt increment. This is the entirity of the code so far, and the timerinterval property has been set and unset during trying to debug, but the behaviour is not affected.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: 5000 in this case means 5000 seconds (not miliseconds).

Comment: Why would this be seconds?

Comment: @mielk is right. The properties window is in seconds (Couldn't find an MSDN reference) But when editing the property with code it is handeled in miliseconds ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff836371.aspx))

Comment: I'm not getting it: from the link you posted @evan "The form's Load event procedure sets the form's TimerInterval property to 1000 so the icon display is toggled once every second" mine then is 5 seconds, and incidently in response to mielk's statement I tried setting it to 1 - it makes no difference to the behaviour - the event is still not firing.

Comment: This from Access context help in the properties window: You can use the TimerInterval property to specify the interval, in milliseconds, between Timer events on a form. Read/write Long.

Comment: I notice if I put the Load event the other way around, i.e starting active at 5000 it runs, but as soon as I click the check box - firing ceases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have realized - the answer is obvious - it is not that the event is not firing at all! But that the rs.MoveNext has not been included in the loop, so it never exits to be able to run the code in the timer event again!!!